# Counting Button pressing times

Tags: objective-c, button

I have a add button on a single view. This button have a same action like showing same labels. 
If i clicked a button once a row will be displayed. If i clicked another time the same labels will show below to the previous label. how can i do this. please give answer with some example code.

```
-(void) addBtnAct
{

[self.view addSubview:sizeDropDownBtn];
deleteBtn.hidden=YES;
[sizeDropDownBtn addSubview:sizeDropDownBtnLbl];
[self.view addSubview:weightDropDownBtn];
[weightDropDownBtn addSubview:weightDropDownBtnLbl];
[self.view addSubview:quantityTxtFld];
[quantityTxtFld addSubview:quantityLbl];
sizeDropDownBtn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 190, 86, 40);
weightDropDownBtn.frame = CGRectMake(110, 190, 86, 40);
quantityTxtFld.frame = CGRectMake(220, 190, 86, 40);
quantityLbl.frame = CGRectMake(10, 12, 100, 15);
sizeDropDownBtnLbl.frame = CGRectMake(20, 12, 100, 15);
weightDropDownBtnLbl.frame = CGRectMake(10,12, 100, 15);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways how to achieve this, you should explain why do you need it.

Simples way is to count somewhere how many rows you have already added and then when adding new row, calculate the appropriate y value. Also you should assign frame first and only then add subview to view.

```
//add this to @interface declaration
@property (nonatomic, assign) int rowCount;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.rowCount = 0;
}

-(void) addBtnAct
{
    UIButton *weightDropDownBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    int y = self.rowCount * 60;
    self.rowCount++;
    weightDropDownBtn.frame = CGRectMake(110, y, 86, 40);
    [self.view addSubview:weightDropDownBtn];

}
```

Comment: i have a add button which is used to get values from user for more than one different items